# Why does App crashes when enableing obfuscate?

Tags: android, androidx

## What happens

App crashes when I set

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
```

### Stacktrace [**IMPORTANT**]

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/app/Application$ActivityLifecycleCallbacks$-CC;
    at androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment$LifecycleCallbacks.onActivityPreStarted(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityPreStarted(Activity.java:1440)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8328)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3869)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2384)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:257)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8384)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1032)
Caused by:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.app.Application$ActivityLifecycleCallbacks$-CC" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~ugieXbyyIvHcIVXooX5mng==/yfdc.douyin.download-n7-gXaRvUZI5UGsPUgYjLA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~ugieXbyyIvHcIVXooX5mng==/yfdc.douyin.download-n7-gXaRvUZI5UGsPUgYjLA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment$LifecycleCallbacks.onActivityPreStarted(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityPreStarted(Activity.java:1440)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8328)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3869)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2384)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:257)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8384)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1032)
```

### My Solution

It works when I use one of these suggestions:

- Upgrate `minSdkVersion` to `28` or Higher;
- disable obfuscate

  However, these suggestions are not my purpose,which I need `minSdkVersion` to set `21`.

Comment: What version of Lifecycle are you using? This was fixed in [Lifecycle 2.2.0-rc02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.2.0-rc02), which was released over 2.5 years ago.

Comment: My lifecycle version is 2.3.01 thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use only:

```
minifyEnabled true
```

Instead of enabling **shrinkResources**: *right click -> Refactor -> Remove Unused Resources*

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't work. I'll try to edit proground file